# Why does the voltage across resistor R decrease as we close the circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

[image]

I understand why there should be an increase in voltage across a capacitor during the charging process of it and why there should be a decrease in current I during that process. What I don't understand is why there should be a drop in voltage across resistor R ?

Comment: $V=IR{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: The voltage source (battery or supply) has a limit based on its design, say 12v or 1.5v, that's the max potential (called voltage it can produce).  So this voltage (like a force) is pushing electrons thru the circuit, as the capacitor charges it gets fuller and fuller until no electrons pass .... all the force ends up at the capacitor, it's like a blocked pipe.

Comment: Well if it didn't decrease then Kirchhoff's loop rule would be violated...

Answer (score 1):

This is a poorly worded problem .

- The answer depends on the charge of the capacitor before the switch is closed.
- Voltage and current are directed quantities, that means you need to specify in which direction you count them to be positive and negative.

Assuming that the Capacitor is empty and we count all voltages and currents to be positive along the direction from + to - of the source, we would get the following

**Before the switch is closed:** all voltages and currents are $0$.

**At time of closing**: The capacitor is basically a short. So the resistor voltage jumps from $0V$ to $V_0$ and the current jumps from  $0A$ to $V_0/R$ , where $V_0$ is the source voltage.

**Shortly after closing**: A charge starts to build up in the capacitor and hence the voltage over the capacitor increases. This leads to current and resistor voltage decreasing

**Long time after closing**: The capacitor is fully charged and the capacitor voltage equals the source voltage $V_0$. The capacitor is basically an open now, so the current and resistor voltage are zero again.

So answer A) is indeed correct. What's confusing here is the difference between "at switch time" and "shortly after switch time". Initially the resistor voltage is $0V$, at switch time it jumps immediately to $V_0$ and that it decays down exponentially to $0V$ again.